# Sql Select a minimum value from a table column and insert the results in another table column in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, minimum

I am trying to get a minimum value from the Candidate table and insert that value in the MinTotal table. Can you do both in one SQL statement?

[image: Snapshot Candidate table]

Here's my SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE MinTotal SET MinTotal.min_total=  MIN(CandidateID.TotalVotes);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a select so you can properly set your MIN().
One way of doing that would be like that:

```
UPDATE MinTotal
SET 
   min_total = Cmin.minresult
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(TotalVotes) as minresult
    from CandidateID
) Cmin
```

In general, that would be one way to solve the Problem. In this case you would set the minresult for every row you have in your MinTotal table. If you dont want that, you may need to be more specific about your desired output and add some examples in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MinTotal   
SET MinTotal.min_total = (
   SELECT MIN(TotalVotes)
   FROM CandidateID 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MinTotal a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(c.TotalVotes) min_vote, c.CandidateID FROM Candidate c 
GROUP BY c.CandidateID) b ON b.CandidateID = a.CandidateID 
SET a.min_total = b.min_vote;
```

Try the above. This is specific for each candidate, else you can use the other answers provided.